# How to find the volume of the region bellow the surface $z=x^2+y^2$ and between $z=0$ and $z=10$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have tried using a double integral with respect to $dydx$. The bounds that I have tried are $0$ to $\pi/2$ and $0$ to $2\pi$. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the intersection of $z = x^2+y^2$ with the plane $z = 10$ is the circle centered in $(0,0,10)$, with radius $\sqrt{10}$. The volume you're looking for is the volume of the cylinder (the obvious one, make a drawing) minus the volume under the graph. More exactly, the volume is: $$V = \pi (\sqrt{10})^210 - \int_Dx^2+y^2\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y,$$where $D = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2 \leq 10 \}$. That last integral in polar coordinates becomes: $$\int_0^{\sqrt{10}}\int_0^{2\pi}r^3\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta.$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for each $z$, you have a circle with $r_z = \sqrt{z}$. Thus, the middle integrals are just the area of these circles.

$$
\int_0^{10} \int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}} \int_{-\sqrt{z-y^2}}^{\sqrt{z-y^2}} 1 \, dxdydz
$$

You could use the polar form as well. It will simplify a lot the middle integrals.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can take $y=0$ so it would reduce to a parabola in a $2$-Dimensional space, now you can revolve the parabola about $z$-axis, so it is a surface of revolution, and the volume is given by

$V =\int_0^{10}\pi x^2dz$

$dz=2xdx$

so, $V =\int_0^\sqrt{10}2\pi x^3dx$